# Filters - Servlets and Spring beans integration NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I have filter executes before servlet:

```
    public class UserFilter implements Filter {


    List<String> sessionIdsList;

    WebContentDAOIF webContentDAOIF;

        public void setWebContentDAOIF(WebContentDAOIF webContentDAOIF) {
            this.webContentDAOIF = webContentDAOIF;
        }


        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

                    sessionIdsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    sessionIdsList = webContentDAOIF.fetchAllSessionIds();

            }


        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                                                     FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

            System.out.println("List size: " + sessionIdsList.size());

                HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;

                HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
                String userSessionId = session.getId();
                System.out.println("Filter: " + userSessionId);

                if(sessionIdsList.size() !=0 && sessionIdsList.contains(userSessionId)) {

                        System.out.println("There is same sessionID");

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Hello anonim");

                }

                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("main");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);


        }


        @Override
        public void destroy() {


            }


}
```

And I have spring context xml file where I declare all my beans:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"> 
            <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>
            <property name="url"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contentDB</value></property> 
            <property name="username"><value>root</value></property>
            <property name="password" ><value>25051988</value></property>

        </bean>


        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="mappingResources">
                <list>
                    <value>user.hbm.xml</value>
                    <value>userEvents.hbm.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>

                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">15</prop>
                </props> 

            </property>

        </bean>


        <bean id="webContentDAOImpl" class="demidov.pkg.persistence.WebContentDAOImpl">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>


        <tx:annotation-driven/>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>


        <bean id="userFilter" class="demidov.pkg.web.UserFilter">
            <property name="webContentDAOIF" ref="webContentDAOImpl"/>
        </bean>
```

I also have filter declared in my web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/*-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

      <filter>
        <filter-name>userFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>demidov.pkg.web.UserFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>userFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>initialContentRendering</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>demidov.pkg.web.InitialContentRendering</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>initialContentRendering</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>orderEventServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>demidov.pkg.web.OrderEventServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>orderEventServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/event</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

But when I load application it says me:

```
   SEVERE: Exception starting filter userFilter
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at demidov.pkg.web.UserFilter.init(UserFilter.java:35)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4562)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5235)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Please help me what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you folks.

Comment: please past complete filter class.

Comment: Yes Sir. I edit filter class on the top of my question

Comment: Paste line 35 in your IDE to the end of this question.  In your code sample line 35 is a blank line.

Comment: The line 35 is  sessionIdsList = webContentDAOIF.fetchAllSessionIds(); I don't understand why I inject in my application-context.xml in bean userFilter property webContentDAOIF" ref="webContentDAOImpl but it says that reference is null. What I did wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to get 2 different instances of your `UserFilter`, one managed by Servlet Container, another by Spring - the UserFilter created by the Servlet Container will of course have a null WebContentDAOIF.

The solution is to let Spring manage your UserFilter (and properly inject the WebContentDAOIF). Then use Spring's [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html), to handle the filtering which ultimately delegates to your UserFilter.

In your web.xml, remove your UserFilter declaration and declare the DelegatingFilterProxy instead.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>userFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>userFilter</param-value>
  </init-param> 
</filter>
```

Comment: Sir it seems like it should work. Please tell me. How it will trigger my userFilter. Like I think it should be some more that just declare all you say in web.xml. I have my own filter in application spring container how can I make him run before servlet executes???

Comment: I updated the answer, original wording was not clear.